# C# get all headers using maikit

Tags: c#, pop3, mailkit

Im trying connect to a pop3 account and getting all emails with all headers included. Im using mailkit for do this task in C#.
The problem is that I searching example of how I can get all header in one string but I dont found the way to do that.

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
{
    try
    {
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
        client.Connect("pop3.host.com", 110, false);
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.Authenticate("mail@host.com", "password");
        for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
        {
                    // below I have the problem. I dont know how request the complete headers of a message/mail
                    header = client.getGetMessageHeaders(i).ToArray;
                    Console.WriteLine("..." + header);
        }
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Checking error: \n\n" + ex.Message + "\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried get Headers in an array for after use this array for give headers to an string, But it isnt possible using this code. I'm C# newbie for that Im requesting some help here.

very thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to serialize all headers to a single string would be to do something like this:

```
var headers = client.GetMessageHeaders (i);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream ()) {
    headers.WriteTo (stream);

    var bytes = memory.ToArray ();
    var latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding (28591);
    string header = latin1.GetString (bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

Keep in mind, however, that each header may contain undeclared 8-bit "text" data which might not be in iso-8859-1 or even UTF-8 (it could be in *any* encoding). Not only that, but each header containing 8-bit "text" data might even be using a *different* encoding.

Trying to represent this as a string is a fool's errand.

Far better to represent it as a Stream or an array of bytes.

If all you want to do is print the headers to the console, you could do something like this instead:

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
{
    try
    {
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
        client.Connect("pop3.host.com", 110, false);
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.Authenticate("mail@host.com", "password");
        for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
        {
                    header = client.GetMessageHeaders(i);
                    header.WriteTo (Console.OpenStandardOutput ());
        }
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Checking error: \n\n" + ex.Message + "\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

Or, if you'd rather see the *decoded* header values:

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
{
    try
    {
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
        client.Connect("pop3.host.com", 110, false);
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.Authenticate("mail@host.com", "password");
        for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
        {
                    var headers = client.GetMessageHeaders(i);
                    foreach (var header in headers)
                        Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1}", header.Field, header.Value);
        }
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Checking error: \n\n" + ex.Message + "\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your examples work for me very well. I will work with on it right now. very thanks my friend